# How to get object ID of specific file stored at currentDirectory on AutodeskForge

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

currently I'm working on forge IDA,
workflow of our code is sending xml file as input through web page(web page just has upload button) and taking ipt files & drawing sheet from BIM360,after performing workitem, storing the output assembly file in OUTPUT folder on current loacation of autodesk forge then converting output folder to zip then downloading it. so as of now bundle(code) is working fine.

now next implemention is showing output(assembly file) on webpage (viewer). as per my understanding I need object id and urn of output file(here sample.iam).

Someone please tell me how to get

1. object id of sample.iam from OUTPUT folder which stored on current location of AutodeskForge.
2. object id of sample.iam from OUTPUT.zip//OUTPUT folder which stored on current location of AutodeskForge.

Any reply is appriciated

Comment: couldn't understand, though, where your file is being stored after the end of the workitem execution? Are you specifying any output URL so design automation can upload the results somewhere? refer to https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/task5-prepare_cloud_storage/#step-6-get-upload-url

Comment: Thanks for reply,

after execution of workitem my zip file is getting upload to bucket.
location :- url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/ivthfjguxx3armw35xira9bdeh8dfmsuoutput/objects/Output.zip.
this zip contains iam, ipt & idw files.
so could you tell me how to get object id of 'sample.iam' from 'output.zip' file which is present in bucket

Answer (score 0):

Since your designs are already in you APs app managed bucket, you can either download results decompress them and reupload or take advantage of [open network](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/open-network-preview) to upload your multiple designs as they get generated from the workitem execution.